# Load content on page scroll with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to load content while scrolling with jQuery and Ajax
I have a problem with this code.
When i scroll and make the ajax call, the var row_tracks doesn't increment and if i comment the ajax request then she increment...

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var position = $(window).scrollTop(), bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

        if (position == bottom) {
            var row_tracks = $('#row_tracks').html(), allcount = $('#count_tracks').html(), rowperpage = 10;
            row_tracks = parseInt(row_tracks) + rowperpage;

            console.log(row_tracks);

            if ($(".list-songs")[0] && row_tracks <= allcount) {
                $('#row_tracks').html(row_tracks);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {row_tracks: row_tracks},
                    success: function(response){
                        $('.list-songs').append(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="list-songs">
  <div class="card mb-4">
 <div class="card-body">
   <div class="card-title">
  <a href="./profil.php?1"><span class="avatar-post"><img class="image_rounded" alt="Avatar" src=""> xxxx</span></a> posted a track in <a href="#">Hip hop</a> 1 day ago <!--./playlist.php?5|1-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2 class="card-title">xxx - xxx</h2>
    <p class="card-text player_single_container">
     <audio class="player_single" data-song-played="4" data-song-id="46" controls="">
    <source src=""></source>
     </audio>
    </p>
    <div class="card my-1">
   <div class="form-group-comment">
     <form action="">
    <input placeholder="Leave comment" name="comment-song" class="form-control">
     </form>
   </div>
    </div>
    <a data-count-likes="0" data-userid="1" data-song-id="46" href="#" class="btn btn-comment like_button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span>0</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-retweet"></i> XXX</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i> Share</a>
    <a href="download.php?46" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
    <div class="pull-right">
   <span class="btn btn-comment-right played"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-play"></i> <span>4</span></span>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment-right"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-comment"></i> XXX</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>      
  <div class="card mb-4">
 <div class="card-body">
   <div class="card-title">
  <a href="./profil.php?1"><span class="avatar-post"><img class="image_rounded" alt="Avatar" src=""> xxxx</span></a> posted a track in <a href="#">Hip hop</a> 1 day ago <!--./playlist.php?5|1-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2 class="card-title">xxx - xxx</h2>
    <p class="card-text player_single_container">
     <audio class="player_single" data-song-played="4" data-song-id="46" controls="">
    <source src=""></source>
     </audio>
    </p>
    <div class="card my-1">
   <div class="form-group-comment">
     <form action="">
    <input placeholder="Leave comment" name="comment-song" class="form-control">
     </form>
   </div>
    </div>
    <a data-count-likes="0" data-userid="1" data-song-id="46" href="#" class="btn btn-comment like_button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span>0</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-retweet"></i> XXX</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i> Share</a>
    <a href="download.php?46" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
    <div class="pull-right">
   <span class="btn btn-comment-right played"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-play"></i> <span>4</span></span>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment-right"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-comment"></i> XXX</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>      
  <div class="card mb-4">
 <div class="card-body">
   <div class="card-title">
  <a href="./profil.php?1"><span class="avatar-post"><img class="image_rounded" alt="Avatar" src=""> xxxx</span></a> posted a track in <a href="#">Hip hop</a> 1 day ago <!--./playlist.php?5|1-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2 class="card-title">xxx - xxx</h2>
    <p class="card-text player_single_container">
     <audio class="player_single" data-song-played="4" data-song-id="46" controls="">
    <source src=""></source>
     </audio>
    </p>
    <div class="card my-1">
   <div class="form-group-comment">
     <form action="">
    <input placeholder="Leave comment" name="comment-song" class="form-control">
     </form>
   </div>
    </div>
    <a data-count-likes="0" data-userid="1" data-song-id="46" href="#" class="btn btn-comment like_button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span>0</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-retweet"></i> XXX</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i> Share</a>
    <a href="download.php?46" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
    <div class="pull-right">
   <span class="btn btn-comment-right played"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-play"></i> <span>4</span></span>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment-right"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-comment"></i> XXX</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>      
  <div class="card mb-4">
 <div class="card-body">
   <div class="card-title">
  <a href="./profil.php?1"><span class="avatar-post"><img class="image_rounded" alt="Avatar" src=""> xxxx</span></a> posted a track in <a href="#">Hip hop</a> 1 day ago <!--./playlist.php?5|1-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2 class="card-title">xxx - xxx</h2>
    <p class="card-text player_single_container">
     <audio class="player_single" data-song-played="4" data-song-id="46" controls="">
    <source src=""></source>
     </audio>
    </p>
    <div class="card my-1">
   <div class="form-group-comment">
     <form action="">
    <input placeholder="Leave comment" name="comment-song" class="form-control">
     </form>
   </div>
    </div>
    <a data-count-likes="0" data-userid="1" data-song-id="46" href="#" class="btn btn-comment like_button"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span>0</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-retweet"></i> XXX</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i> Share</a>
    <a href="download.php?46" class="btn btn-comment"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
    <div class="pull-right">
   <span class="btn btn-comment-right played"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-play"></i> <span>4</span></span>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-comment-right"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-comment"></i> XXX</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span class="hidden" id="row_tracks">0</span>
<span class="hidden" id="count_tracks">43</span>
```

When I make the ajax request, **row_tracks** doesn't increment...
[image]

If i comment the ajax call then it increment...

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Post your HTML, please. Are you getting any console error?

Comment: No error in console